# Finding the Laurent series of the function $f(z) = \frac{1 - 2z}{(z^2 - z)^2}$ on the annulus $\Delta^*(0,1)$ (i.e. $0 < |z| < 1$)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

I am tasked to find the Laurent series of the function $f(z) = \frac{1 - 2z}{(z^2 - z)^2}$ on the annulus $\Delta^*(0,1) = \{z \in \mathbb{C}\mid 0 < |z| < 1\}$. The hint I have been given is to consider first the Laurent series of the function $g(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 - z}$. I have identified that $f'(z) = g(z)$ therefore suggesting that the termwise derivative of $f$'s Laurent series is $g$'s Laurent series on $\Delta^*(0,1)$. What I am unsure about is the convergence of $g$'s series on the said annulus. To be specific,

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{z - 1} = \frac{-1}{z}\frac{1 - z} = \frac{-1}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = -\left(\frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n\right)$$$

Therefore,

$$g(z) = f'(z) = \frac{1}{z^2} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty nz^{n-1} = \frac{1}{z^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1} = \frac{1}{z^2} - \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n + 1)z^n$$

Now, $\left|\frac{(n+2)z^{n+1}}{(n+1)z^n}\right| = \left|\frac{(n+2)z}{(n+1)}\right| < 1 \Longleftrightarrow 1 < \frac{n+2}{n+1} < |z|$ which surely does not hold on $\Delta^*(0,1)$.

How should I modify my approach or have I missed something?

As a bonus question: Is it true that the termwise derivative/integral of a Laurent series on a given annulus remains as a valid Laurent series after the said transformation?

Comment: You last inequality should be $|z|<\frac{n+1}{n+2}$, which is what follows from the previous inequality. However, that previous inequality is not the condition that you need for convergence. It should be the limit $|z|$ of $\left|\frac{(n+2)z}{n+1}\right|$ what you need to be less than $1$.

Comment: I guess at the end you are applying the d'Alembert  test so you need to take a limit which is equal $|z|.$ That's why the series is convergent for $|z|<1.$

Answer (score 1):

Take my answer with a grain of salt because I did the calculations a bit fast. So, $$f(z)=\frac{1-2z}{z^2(1-z)^2}=\frac{1-z-z}{z^2(1-z)^2}=\frac{1-z}{z^2(1-z)^2}-\frac{z}{z^2(1-z)^2}=\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{1-z}-\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}\frac{1}{z}.$$
So we use the geometric series here for $\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ centered at 0 with $0<|z|<1.$ We get:
$$\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n-\frac{1}{z}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^{n-1}$$
which is equal to:
$$\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n-\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^{n}=\frac{1}{z^2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nz^{n}\right)=\frac{1}{z^2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nz^n\right)=\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-n)z^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-n)z^{n-2}.$$

Please check the calculations again, and let me know if I made any mistake. Hope it is alright mate, have a good one!